# iOS Universal Links not working within Safari but working from everywhere else

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I managed to make Universal Linking working in our App 99% to perfection, but I'm still struggling to make it work reliably within Safari.

This is what happens:

- If I get a link from either our www or non-www domain in Gmail, both launch the apps correctly;
- If I write the URL from either our www or non-www domain in Notes, both launch the apps correctly;
- In Safari / Chrome, only the links from the non-www domain launch the app reliably, 100% of the times;
- In Safari / Chrome, the www version of our links *sometimes* launch the app, but always stop working after the first tap;
- In Safari, if I longpress a www version of a link, it does show the "Open in App" context option;
- I configured our app to handle both our wwww and non-www domains; we use React Native / Expo, so this is what we have under `ios.associatedDomains`:

```
"associatedDomains": [
        "applinks:www.mydomain.com",
        "applinks:mydomain.com"
      ]
```

Regarding the AASA, it's located on `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` and returns context-type correctly (json):

```json
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": ["MYTEAMID.com.ourcompany.ourfirstapp"],
        "components": [
          {
            "/": "/first-app/path",
            "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /first-app/path"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "appID": "MYTEAMID.com.ourcompany.ourfirstapp",
        "paths": [ "/first-app/path" ]
      },
      {
        "appIDs": ["MYTEAMID.com.ourcompany.oursecondapp"],
        "components": [
          {
            "/": "/second-app",
            "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /second-app"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "appID": "MYTEAMID.com.ourcompany.oursecondapp",
        "paths": [ "/second-app" ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "activitycontinuation": {
    "apps": [
      "MYTEAMID.com.ourcompany.ourfirstapp",
      "MYTEAMID.com.ourcompany.oursecondapp"
    ]
  }
}
```

I currently have no idea how to fix the safari/chrome behavior for the www domain links.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the answer. Quoting from the Branch documentation:

> Universal Links will not work with a user-driven 
> element click on the same domain. For example, if there is a Universal
> Link on google.com pointing to a different Universal Link on
> google.com, it will not open the app.

In my case, the www links that didn't work were linked from a page I was hosting within the same www domain, so they were not expected to work at all.